# Implementing "Someone is typing..." functionality in chat application using firebase cloud pub/sub

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat, google-cloud-pubsub

I have ported the web version of the [friendlychat](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat) example into the angular 4 suite. You can see mine live [over here](http://www.somombo.com) and it appears to be working okay... I shall publish it opensource shortly.

Now I want to implement a feature that is such that when a User A starts typing then in realtime, user B should see a "User A is typing...." message. And when User A stops typing the message should disappear. Obviously, User A shouldn't see the message if he himself is typing.

I am considering just having an object in the db like so:

```json
{
  "isTyping":true,
  "fromDeviceToken": "xxxx"
}
```

... and then just altering the `isTyping` field using firebase realtime.

Any better ideas about how can I achieve this? Any comments/improvements?

My Main question is,

**Can a Firebase Cloud [pub/sub trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) be used to do this without persisting the typing state in the db .. If so, how?**

Comment: You may want to clearly define what 'is typing' means. Does it mean they started to type and when they send the message they are not typing? What if they start to type and change their mind and delete the text? Also, you need to persist the status of typing in a node in the database as the client will be listening for events on that node so they know when to display Is Typing or not.

Comment: I think it cant get any more clear as actual working example code.. So [at this repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) and [live over here](https://socket.io/demos/chat/), is the example of precisely what I want to achieve. Pay particular attention to the `index.js` sever code and the `public/main.js` client code.. search for the word "typing" in those files. . From this example, it is shown that it is possible in general to correctly transfer an "is typing" message  through barebones websockets, _**without**_ the need to persist *anything* in a database.

Comment: So to re-emphasize, I already know or have a very good idea how to do this  "is typing" by persisting something in the firebase realtime db. My question, is how to do it in the style reminiscent of the socket.io chat example using firebase but without unnecessarily persisting data (i.e. either by using cloud functions, or perhaps some other firebase feature I'm unaware of). @StuckBetweenTrees, I hope this ^ clarifies this better

Answer (score 3):

If user A connection is lost during typing then the status will be always remain true until he resumes the connection. To solve this problem you can have one DateTime field in your firebase object. Let say lastTypedCharacter and store DateTime and update it every second when user A is typing anything. When showing to the other user B match the lastTypedCharacter DateTime with the current time if its less than 5 seconds then you can assume that the user A is no longer typing

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
 this.messageInput.onkeyup = function(){
    So when user starts typing update your database and set isTyping true. 
    Dont forget to check if isTyping set to true so it will not update every 
    time user presses the key
}
```

Sample got from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mEefW/)

Comment: this is a question about firebase, and preferably firebase's cloud pub-sub. You have mentioned neither.

Comment: You can't show something to an user without triggering the db and your live project is based on firebase sample for web which is using js as my answer shows you how to achieve in order to display for user is typing text